# Cannot Access .size withAttributes: from String

Tags: ios, swift, string, size, swift-extensions

I have a `String` extension:

```
func iconName(identifier: String) -> String
{
    return self.library()[identifier]
}
```

and I'm doing this inside a `UIImage` extension:

```
let icon = String.iconName("myiconname")
var iconSize = icon.size(withAttributes: someAttributes)
```

I get an error:

```
Value of type '(String) -> String' has no member 'size'
```

I have tried to switch this around many different ways and I get the same (or similar) error each time.

The thing is it does have a member size. I can do this with no error:

```
var myString = "testing"
myString.size(withAttributes: attributes)
```

Anyone know what is going on with the `Value of type '(String) -> String'`?

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
size(withAttributes:)
```

is an instance method inside `NSString` not `String`

see here in [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1531844-size)

So , you can change signature of the method to

```
func iconName(identifier: String) -> NSString {....}
```

//

You should not use

```
let icon = String.iconName("myiconname") // here String is a generic type
```

as extension is designated to be used with an object like

```
let icon = "someStringValue".iconName("myiconname")
```

Comment: When I change the return type the error changes to return type of NSString -> String has no member or String -> NSString has no member. Can't seem to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a `String` extension here because the return is of type `(String) -> String` which is not the same as type `String` and the extension will not allow you to cast its type. I assume you chose an extension to make it globally accessible but there are other options. You can make the function itself global (which I don't find attractive), you can make the function `static` within a regular `class` or `struct`, you can make the `struct` `static`, you can do the singleton pattern, you can store the function in the app delegate and call it there--you have a list of options to make properties and methods "global".

Because all that this method does is take a `String` and convert it into a modified `String`, no need for singleton, and so I would most likely create a global class with static properties.

```
class Globals {

    static func iconName(_ identifier: String) -> String {
        return "slickDaddy"
    }

}

let icon = Globals.iconName("myIconName")
var iconSize = icon.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: UIColor.blue])

print(iconSize) // prints (58.01953125, 13.8)
```

You can call this method from anywhere in the app. Certainly consider all of the other iterations I mentioned above and use the one that suits you best. Furthermore, even if you could do this in an extension, I personally wouldn't. This is a business method used in very special cases, not a method that modifies the style of a `String` that is used all over the app (which is what I think extensions should be primarily used for).